# Error: 'list' object is not callable

Tags: python-3.x, list, compare

I'm trying to make a program that will pick up randomly a name from a file. The user would be asked if he wants to pick up another one again (by pressing 1). 
The names can't be picked up twice.
Once picked up, the names would be stocked in a list, written into a file.
When all the names are picked up, the program would be able to restart from the beginning.
I checked other similar problems, but I still don't get it...

```
from random import *

#import a list of name from a txt file
def getL1():
    l1 = open("Employees.txt", "r")
    list1 = []
    x = 0
    for line in l1:
        list1.append(line)
        x = x+1
    list1 = [el.replace('\n', '') for el in list1]

    #print("list" 1 :",list)

    return list1
#import an empty list (that will be filled by tested employees) during
#execution of the program
def getL2():
    l2 = open("tested.txt", "r")
    list2 = []

    for line in l2:
        list2.append(line)
    list2 = [el.replace('\n', '') for el in list2]

    #print("list 2 :",list2)
    l2.close()
    return list2


def listCompare():
    employees = getL1()#acquire first list from employee file
    tested = getL2()#acquire second list from tested file
    notTested = []# declare list to hole the results of the compare
    for val in employees:
        if val not in tested: #find employee values not present in tested
            #print(val) 
            notTested.append(val)#append value to the notTested list
    return notTested

def listCount():
    x=0
    employees = getL1()
    tested = getL2()
    for val in employees:
        if val not in tested:
            x = x+1

    return x
#add the names of tested employees the the second second file
def addTested(x):
    appendFile = open("tested.txt", "a")
    appenFile.write(x)
    appendFile.write('\n')
    appendFile.close()



def main():

    entry = 1
    while entry == 1:

        pickFrom = listCompare()
        if listCount() > 0:
            y = randint (0, (listCount ()-1))
            print ('\n' + "Random Employee to be tested is: ", pickFrom(y), "\n")
            addTested(pickFrom[y])
            try:
                entry = int(input("Would you like to test another employee? Enter 1:"))

            except:
                print("The entry must be a number")
                entry = 0
        else:
            print("\n/\ new cycle has begun")
            wipeFile = open("tested.txt", "w")

    print ("goodbye")
main()
```

The last error that I have is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prog.py", line 78, in <module>
    main()
  File "prog.py", line 65, in main
    print ('\n' + "Random Employee to be tested is: ", pickFrom(y), "\n")
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Comment: List objects need to be called using `[ ]`

Comment: Thank you, I feel stupid... I was stuck for so long because of that stupid thing !

Comment: Happens to the best of us ! Good luck ! Answer posted accept if that solves the issue :)

Comment: BTW, numerous improvements could be made to this program. Why do you have two file reading functions? What's `x` for in `getL1`?  Why do you strip newlines manually instead of using `.splitlines`? Why do you keep reading the same files, over and over? Why does you `main` loop call `listCount()` twice? Why do `appenFile.write(x); appendFile.write('\n')` instead of `appenFile.write(x + '\n')`? Etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the code print `pickFrom` is a list and when you are referencing it in the print it needs to be called using [ ]. Change it to `pickFrom[y]`

Comment: Please don't write full answers to typo questions, just reply in a comment. Typo questions are unlikely to help future readers since they'd be almost impossible find via a search, even if you have the exact same problem. So the system tries to delete such questions after a few days, but upvoted / accepted answers interfere with that process.